# azure search work around $skip limit

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm doing a job to check if all records from my database exists on Azure Search (around 610k). However there's a 100000 limit with the $skip parameter. Is there a way to work around this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not facet over more thank 100K documents, however, you can add facets to work around this.  For example, let’s say you have a facet called Country and no one facet has more than 100K documents.  You can facet over all documents where Country == ‘Canada’, then facet over all documents where Country == ‘USA’, etc…

Answer (score 2):

I use data **metadata_storage_last_modified** as filter, and the following is my example.

```
    offset           skip              time
     0         --%-->  0
     100,000   --%-->  100,000      getLastTime
     101,000   --%-->  0            useLastTime
     200,000   --%-->   99,000      useLastTime
     201,000   --%-->  100,000      useLastTime & getLastTime
     202,000   --%-->  0            useLastTime
```

Because Skip limit is 100k, so we can calculate skip by

```
AzureSearchSkipLimit = 100k
AzureSearchTopLimit = 1k
skip = offset % (AzureSearchSkipLimit + AzureSearchTopLimit)
```

If total search count will large than **AzureSearchSkipLimit**, then apply

```
orderby = "metadata_storage_last_modified desc"
```

When skip reach **AzureSearchSkipLimit** ,then get **metadata_storage_last_modified** time from end of data. And put **metadata_storage_last_modified** as next 100k search filer.

```
filter = metadata_storage_last_modified lt ${metadata_storage_last_modified}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the other answers: you can't bypass the limit directly but you can use a workaround.

Here's what you can do:

1) Add a unique field to the index. The contents can be a modification timestamp (if it's granular enough to make it unique) or for example a running number. Or alternatively you can use some existing unique field for this.

2) Take the first 100000 results from the index ordered by your unique field

3) Check what is the maximum value (if ordering ascending) in the results for your unique field - so the value of the last entry

4) Take the next 100000 results by ordering based on the same unique field and adding a filter which takes results only where the unique field's value is bigger that the previous maximum. This way the same first 100000 values are not returned but we get the next 100000 values.

5) Continue until you have all results

The downside is that you can't use other custom ordering with the results unless you do the ordering after getting the results.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the limitation of the API with the 100K limit, and MS's site says as a work around "you can work around this limitation by adding code to iterate over, and filter on, a facet with less that 100K documents per facet value."

I'm using the "Back up and restore an Azure Cognitive Search index" sample solution provided by MS. (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-dotnet-samples)

But can some when tell me where or how I implement this "iterate loop" on a facet" The facetable field I'm trying to use is "tribtekey" but I don't know where to place the code in the below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// This is a prototype tool that allows for extraction of data from a search index
// Since this tool is still under development, it should not be used for production usage

using Azure;
using Azure.Search.Documents;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureSearchBackupRestore
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string SourceSearchServiceName;
        private static string SourceAdminKey;
        private static string SourceIndexName;
        private static string TargetSearchServiceName;
        private static string TargetAdminKey;
        private static string TargetIndexName;
        private static string BackupDirectory;

        private static SearchIndexClient SourceIndexClient;
        private static SearchClient SourceSearchClient;
        private static SearchIndexClient TargetIndexClient;
        private static SearchClient TargetSearchClient;

        private static int MaxBatchSize = 500;          // JSON files will contain this many documents / file and can be up to 1000
        private static int ParallelizedJobs = 10;       // Output content in parallel jobs

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Get source and target search service info and index names from appsettings.json file
            //Set up source and target search service clients
            ConfigurationSetup();

            //Backup the source index
            Console.WriteLine("\nSTART INDEX BACKUP");
            BackupIndexAndDocuments();

            //Recreate and import content to target index
           //Console.WriteLine("\nSTART INDEX RESTORE");
           //DeleteIndex();
           //CreateTargetIndex();
           //ImportFromJSON();
           //Console.WriteLine("\r\n  Waiting 10 seconds for target to index content...");
           //Console.WriteLine("  NOTE: For really large indexes it may take longer to index all content.\r\n");
           //Thread.Sleep(10000);
           //
           //// Validate all content is in target index
           //int sourceCount = GetCurrentDocCount(SourceSearchClient);
           //int targetCount = GetCurrentDocCount(TargetSearchClient);
           //Console.WriteLine("\nSAFEGUARD CHECK: Source and target index counts should match");
           //Console.WriteLine(" Source index contains {0} docs", sourceCount);
           //Console.WriteLine(" Target index contains {0} docs\r\n", targetCount);
           //
           //Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
           //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ConfigurationSetup()
        {

            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            SourceSearchServiceName = configuration["SourceSearchServiceName"];
            SourceAdminKey = configuration["SourceAdminKey"];
            SourceIndexName = configuration["SourceIndexName"];
            TargetSearchServiceName = configuration["TargetSearchServiceName"];
            TargetAdminKey = configuration["TargetAdminKey"];
            TargetIndexName = configuration["TargetIndexName"];
            BackupDirectory = configuration["BackupDirectory"];

            Console.WriteLine("CONFIGURATION:");
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Source service and index {0}, {1}", SourceSearchServiceName, SourceIndexName);
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Target service and index: {0}, {1}", TargetSearchServiceName, TargetIndexName);
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Backup directory: " + BackupDirectory);

            SourceIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(new Uri("https://" + SourceSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net"), new AzureKeyCredential(SourceAdminKey));
            SourceSearchClient = SourceIndexClient.GetSearchClient(SourceIndexName);

       
           // TargetIndexClient = new SearchIndexClient(new Uri($"https://" + TargetSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net"), new AzureKeyCredential(TargetAdminKey));
           // TargetSearchClient = TargetIndexClient.GetSearchClient(TargetIndexName);
       }

        static void BackupIndexAndDocuments()
        {
            // Backup the index schema to the specified backup directory
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Backing up source index schema to {0}\r\n", BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + ".schema");

            File.WriteAllText(BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + ".schema", GetIndexSchema());

            // Extract the content to JSON files 
            int SourceDocCount = GetCurrentDocCount(SourceSearchClient);
            WriteIndexDocuments(SourceDocCount);     // Output content from index to json files
        }

        static void WriteIndexDocuments(int CurrentDocCount)
        {
            // Write document files in batches (per MaxBatchSize) in parallel
            string IDFieldName = GetIDFieldName();
            int FileCounter = 0;
            for (int batch = 0; batch <= (CurrentDocCount / MaxBatchSize); batch += ParallelizedJobs)
            {

                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                for (int job = 0; job < ParallelizedJobs; job++)
                {
                    FileCounter++;
                    int fileCounter = FileCounter;
                    if ((fileCounter - 1) * MaxBatchSize < CurrentDocCount)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("  Backing up source documents to {0} - (batch size = {1})", BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + fileCounter + ".json", MaxBatchSize);

                        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            ExportToJSON((fileCounter - 1) * MaxBatchSize, IDFieldName, BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + fileCounter + ".json")
                        ));
                    }

                }
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());  // Wait for all the stored procs in the group to complete
            }

            return;
        }

        static void ExportToJSON(int Skip, string IDFieldName, string FileName)
        {
            // Extract all the documents from the selected index to JSON files in batches of 500 docs / file
            string json = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
                {
                    SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
                    Size = MaxBatchSize,
                    Skip = Skip,
                     
                  // ,IncludeTotalCount = true
                  // ,Filter = Azure.Search.Documents.SearchFilter.Create('%24top=2&%24skip=0&%24orderby=tributeId%20asc')
                  //,Filter = String.Format("&search=*&%24top=2&%24skip=0&%24orderby=tributeId%20asc")
                  //,Filter = "%24top=2&%24skip=0&%24orderby=tributeId%20asc"
                  //,Filter = "tributeKey eq '5'"




                };

                SearchResults<SearchDocument> response = SourceSearchClient.Search<SearchDocument>("*", options);

                foreach (var doc in response.GetResults())
                {
                    json += JsonSerializer.Serialize(doc.Document) + ",";
                    json = json.Replace("\"Latitude\":", "\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [");
                    json = json.Replace("\"Longitude\":", "");
                    json = json.Replace(",\"IsEmpty\":false,\"Z\":null,\"M\":null,\"CoordinateSystem\":{\"EpsgId\":4326,\"Id\":\"4326\",\"Name\":\"WGS84\"}", "]");
                    json += "\r\n";
                }

                // Output the formatted content to a file
                json = json.Substring(0, json.Length - 3); // remove trailing comma
                File.WriteAllText(FileName, "{\"value\": [");
                File.AppendAllText(FileName, json);
                File.AppendAllText(FileName, "]}");
                Console.WriteLine("  Total documents: {0}", response.GetResults().Count().ToString());
                json = string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        static string GetIDFieldName()
        {
            // Find the id field of this index
            string IDFieldName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var schema = SourceIndexClient.GetIndex(SourceIndexName);
                foreach (var field in schema.Value.Fields)
                {
                    if (field.IsKey == true)
                    {
                        IDFieldName = Convert.ToString(field.Name);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return IDFieldName;
        }

        static string GetIndexSchema()
        {

            // Extract the schema for this index
            // We use REST here because we can take the response as-is

            Uri ServiceUri = new Uri("https://" + SourceSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net");
            HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", SourceAdminKey);

            string Schema = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, "/indexes/" + SourceIndexName);
                HttpResponseMessage response = AzureSearchHelper.SendSearchRequest(HttpClient, HttpMethod.Get, uri);
                AzureSearchHelper.EnsureSuccessfulSearchResponse(response);
                Schema = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return Schema;
        }

        private static bool DeleteIndex()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Delete target index {0} in {1} search service, if it exists", TargetIndexName, TargetSearchServiceName);
            // Delete the index if it exists
            try
            {
                TargetIndexClient.DeleteIndex(TargetIndexName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error deleting index: {0}\r\n", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("  Did you remember to set your SearchServiceName and SearchServiceApiKey?\r\n");
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        static void CreateTargetIndex()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Create target index {0} in {1} search service", TargetIndexName, TargetSearchServiceName);
            // Use the schema file to create a copy of this index
            // I like using REST here since I can just take the response as-is

            string json = File.ReadAllText(BackupDirectory + "\\" + SourceIndexName + ".schema");

            // Do some cleaning of this file to change index name, etc
            json = "{" + json.Substring(json.IndexOf("\"name\""));
            int indexOfIndexName = json.IndexOf("\"", json.IndexOf("name\"") + 5) + 1;
            int indexOfEndOfIndexName = json.IndexOf("\"", indexOfIndexName);
            json = json.Substring(0, indexOfIndexName) + TargetIndexName + json.Substring(indexOfEndOfIndexName);

            Uri ServiceUri = new Uri("https://" + TargetSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net");
            HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", TargetAdminKey);

            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, "/indexes");
                HttpResponseMessage response = AzureSearchHelper.SendSearchRequest(HttpClient, HttpMethod.Post, uri, json);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        static int GetCurrentDocCount(SearchClient searchClient)
        {
            // Get the current doc count of the specified index
            try
            {
                SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
                {
                    SearchMode = SearchMode.All,
                    IncludeTotalCount = true
                };

                SearchResults<Dictionary<string, object>> response = searchClient.Search<Dictionary<string, object>>("*", options);
                return Convert.ToInt32(response.TotalCount);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            return -1;
        }

        static void ImportFromJSON()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Upload index documents from saved JSON files");
            // Take JSON file and import this as-is to target index
            Uri ServiceUri = new Uri("https://" + TargetSearchServiceName + ".search.windows.net");
            HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("api-key", TargetAdminKey);

            try
            {
                foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(BackupDirectory, SourceIndexName + "*.json"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  -Uploading documents from file {0}", fileName);
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                    Uri uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, "/indexes/" + TargetIndexName + "/docs/index");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = AzureSearchHelper.SendSearchRequest(HttpClient, HttpMethod.Post, uri, json);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```