# Retrieve more than 100k results from Cognitive Search

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, azure-cognitive-search

I've got an Azure Search Index with well over 100,000 documents. It has two retrievable fields, both are arbitrary string IDs determined by third parties. It has a lot more searchable and sortable fields.

I need to be able to retrieve every document in the index. My application's consumers may provide no filter or filters resulting in over 100k documents.

I can deal with the `$top=1000` limitation but, no matter what I do, the `$skip=100000` limitation keeps biting me. I'm using [v10.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search/10.1.0) of the .NET Core SDK. I've removed code which aggregates the results, this just shows my looping.

```cs
var results = index.Documents.Search("*", searchParameters: new SearchParameters
{
  Top = int.MaxValue // I should have fewer than 2B docs...
});

while (results.ContinuationToken != null)
{
  results = index.Documents.ContinueSearch(results.ContinuationToken);
}
```

Once this gets 101k results (top 1k and skip 100k), it will either stop or crash, depending on what kind of guard rails I have around the `ContinueSearch` call.

I've also tried this over HTTP with essentially the same results.

I'm open to any solution that targets .NET Core 3.1. I'm not married to any particular packages or even language as long as it works.

Comment: You might consider outputting documents to a Knowledge Store. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/knowledge-store-concept-intro

Comment: If I am not mistaken, max 100K documents limit is imposed by Azure Search.

Comment: @GauravMantri Right, it won't return more than 100k but it can store more than 100k. In the portal, I see 718,776 documents on the Search service index dashboard.

Comment: That's correct. I remember talking to Azure Search PM long time back and he mentioned about this limitation. Did not explain me the reason behind this limitation though.

Comment: The 100K limit is for performance reasons. Each page takes progressively more resources to fetch since paging is stateless. It helps to think of Azure Cognitive Search as a search engine and not a database. As for workarounds, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067478/azure-search-work-around-skip-limit

Comment: @BruceJohnston that's a possible workaround. I just got word that we're going to stick to the 100k limit for end users who want to filter results. I understand the technical limitations now and would file the use case I described as "misuse".