# How to do pagination in Azure cognitive search

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am wondering if there is way to do pagination in cognitive search for very high volumes of data.

We have been using $top and $skip. so if the page size is 50, i want to go to page 2, the query would be $top=50&$skip=50.

This works fine until 1999 pages. While trying to display the 2000th page, the query would be $top=50&$skip=100000. This is where Azure cognitive search api is throwing an error `"Value must be between 0 and 100000.\r\nParameter name: $skip"`.

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [azure search work around $skip limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067478/azure-search-work-around-skip-limit)

Answer (score 2):

The limit of results from Azure Cognitive Search is 100,000. This is by design.